# What is the difference between "storage/emulated/0" and "storage/caf-999"

Tags: android, android-11, android-storage

Updated my Android version to 11 and found this

[image]

**What is the difference between "storage/emulated/0" and "storage/caf-999"**

Answer (score 0):

/storage/emulated/0/Download is the actual path to the files.

/sdcard/Download is a symlink to the actual path of /storage/emulated/0/Download

However, the actual files are located in the filesystem in /data/media, which is then mounted to /storage/emulated/999 (and often other mountpoints as well)

A Symlink In computing, a symbolic link is a term for any file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution. Symbolic links were already present by 1978 in minicomputer operating systems from DEC and Data General's RDOS.